# Lookup list does not exist error

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio

While looping through my sharepoint's list fields, I found that there are some "in-built" Sharepoint fields (for example, Check In Comment) that are lookup fields. However, when I try to use

```
lookupField.LookupList
```

to find which list they are pointing at, I get an error that lookup list does not exist. Can someone tell me why this is so? If it's a lookup field, it surely MUST have a lookup list right?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. There are some built-in fields (like "Last_x0020_Modified", "Created_x0020_Date") that are lookup fields, but without any lookup list in the background. These are handled by SharePoint internally, and not very well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree these are not well documented! Have been looking on google almost whole day yesterday...